# MassTransit in AWS Lambda

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, .net-6.0, masstransit

I am using MassTransit v7 with Asp.Net Core running on Aws Lambda and I want to upgrade to v8. I want to know what is the proper way to use MassTransit in a serverless environment.

The problem I see is with background/hosted services and how MassTransit uses them. According to my understanding, background services do not work properly with Aws Lambda environment and should be avoided.

The "Common Mistakes" section states that the bus has to be always started:

> When creating a bus instance only to send or publish messages, it must be started. Failure to start the bus can lead to some strange side effects. Every bus, even ones without receiving endpoints, must be started (and eventually stopped).

With the changes to v8, it seems that MassTransit will automatically add an IHostedService for MassTransit and start it.

Because the bus is used as a hosted service there might be situations where publish operation does not send the message. Simply put, Lambda will stop execution when the http request ends but before the background service actually processes and sends the message.

The other problem with MassTransit and Lambdas is that currently, the nature of Aws Lambda requires that we split every project into multiple lambdas in a funky way for eg.:

1. Api aplication - Asp.net core api
2. Native lambdas that process messages from the broker. They are based on MassTransit lambda sample.

ad. 1) An API application that receives http requests and publishes messages. First of all, it should not be able to consume any messages. This lambda only works in the context of http request. When the request ends and a message is received in the background, it can lead to strange outcomes.

Second of all, whenever it publishes a message it should do it synchronously, wait for a response from the bus and not do it through a background service. Background services do not work properly in this environment.

ad. 2) Those are very similar to the MassTransit [lambda sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-LambdaFunction). The difference is that we  also want to publish messages when we are processing events:

```
public class SubmitOrderConsumer : IConsumer<SubmitOrder>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SubmitOrder> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("YUS");
        // TODO: write something to S3
        // ...
        // PUBLISH / SEND with MassTransit
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The same rules apply here. There should be no operations that are delegated to the background thread.

**Is there a way to configure and use MassTransit without background services and to use synchronous publish?
Or Am I misunderstanding some fundamental concepts?**

Comment: The obvious choices for serverless applications are Azure Service Bus/Azure Queues on Azure and Amazon SQS on AWS. You can set up both to start the Azure Function/AWS Lambda on message arrival and hence you don't have the problems described above that the serverless app gets killed before processing is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but since you only want to publish messages through MassTransit, the sample you linked using the receive endpoint dispatcher should work for you. And any messages published through the `ConsumeContext<T>` should be publish, as long as the `Publish` call is awaited (publishing is not done in the background, it's just *async*).

You'd only need to add the:

```cs
x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) => { /* configure host */ });
```

instead of `UsingInMemory`.

Since the AWS SDK is all HTTP calls under the hood, without any persistent sockets, it should be fine. Mind you, I'm only saying this about SQS because of how it works (includes SNS as well). Since it's all HTTP, and no receive endpoints, not starting the bus shouldn't cause any negative effects.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly well with v7. However, v8 added "AddHostedService" with "AddMassTransit". Because of this, the bus is started in the background and it tries to consume messages. This leads to unexpected behavior in AWS Lambda. This is a breaking change and it also breaks the Aws Lambda Sample. On one hand, the message is consumed "manually" through IReceiveEndpointDispatcher, and on the other, there is a background task that tries to consume the messages directly from SQS (which leads to errors due background task not being respected in lambda). Is there a way to disable this in v8?

Comment: Uh, so, who started it? Because it sure isn't AWS starting it. Hosted services don't magically start by themselves and AWS Lambda don't know anything about your service collection. In fact, it doesn't even get disposed.

Comment: I wanted to ask for some more clarification. The hosted services will be added to the service collection but it will not be started in the AWS Lambda as in the sample code in Masstransit repo. BUT When I am running full-fledged Asp.Net inside using Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer, I do in fact get the log "Starting bus instances:", "Bus started:" even though this app is only a producer and does not have ReceiveEndpoints calls. Is there a way in 8.x to not start the bus when it is not needed?

Comment: Even if you're producing only, you should start the bus to manage the broker connection.